# Where to write my code in main.cpp or in mainwindow.cpp

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning how to make GUI with QT in C++ and I don't know where to write my actual code. I'm writing simple program that will connect to server. But where I should initialize the socket in main.cpp or in mainwindow.cpp ?

Comment: Could you post the code you have now?

Comment: Avoid putting code in `mainwindow.cpp` which doesn't have anything to do with the GUI. Keyword here is [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't have anything to do with the GUI", QT creator generates code there for me.

Comment: QtCreator doesn't generate all of your code, does it? You asked where to put "your actual code". If this actual code is related to your MainWindow GUI: put it in mainwindow.cpp, if it is not (if it is about managing your data, or implementing some logic which is not related to your GUI): put it outside (e.g. in main.cpp or somwehere else).

Comment: In general, when you ask yourself if you should put the code in mainwindow.cpp, ask yourself if this makes sense if you had *another* user interface, probably non-graphical, if the code is as equally related to *that* user interface as it is to your MainWindow GUI. If it is, it's non-GUI related. Example: if your application shows a calendar, storing and sorting the calendar events is not a GUI-related logic. But displaying them is.

Comment: You probably should not be putting your socket connection code in either main.cpp or mainwindow.cpp. Create your own class that handles this.

Comment: Well I have do it by all the ways you guys told me, I find creating new class to handle it for most organized so I will leave it this way, I'm grateful to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no rule for that. Just make sure to end the connection and close the socket and correctly at the right time. If the socket will be used in your main window only, mainwindow.cpp would be good

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. But to make things clear, is there any situation that I shoudl prefer to use main.cpp rather than mainwindow.cpp

Comment: May be! it all depends on the design and lifetime of your objects in the application

Answer (score 1):

In very simple situations, you can consider putting you socket code into some gui class.

Putting it into main() should be considered in special cases, only.

The Qt - way is probably to look at the model-view approach. Sockets will, most likely, be your "model".